# (camera calibration) Type Error: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

The error `Expected Ptr<cv:::UMat>for argument'%s'` occurred during camera calibration. What is the cause of this error, and how to fix it?

```
def findCorner(img) :
    CHECKERBOARD=(6,9)
    criteria=(cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS+cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,30,0.001)
    ret, corners=cv.findChessboardCorners(images,(6,9),None)
    corner_refine = cv.cornerSubPix(images, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER), criteria)
    corner_img = cv.drawChessboardCorners(images, CHECKERBOARD, corner_refine, ret)
    return ret, corner_refine, corner_img
objpoints = []
imgpoints = []
corner_imgs = []

for img in images : 

  ret, corner, corner_img = findCorner(img)

  if ret == True :
    objpoints.append(objp)
    imgpoints.append(corner)
    corner_imgs.append(corner_img)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could we see the entire traceback?  Also, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to better frame your question.

Comment: @judith I faced this error too while using cv2's `solvePnp()`

Comment: Well I was able to fix it by converting by inputs to float64

Comment: See [calibrate.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.3.0/samples/python/calibrate.py), the sample file for camera calibration.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing images, probably a string or folder location where the images are stored. But your parameter is img and you also loop through images. Opencv is expecting an Opencv image read from your folder "images".

So I would change it to:

```
ret, corners=cv.findChessboardCorners(img,(6,9),None)
corner_refine = cv.cornerSubPix(img, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER), criteria)
```